Calling API hosted in kubernetes using kubernetes local dns (svc.cluster.local) throwing mixed content error
I have a Frontend based on React JS hosted in a Kubernetes cluster which should call the Backend API hosted in the same cluster and namespace. Since they are part of the same cluster I tried calling the API using the URL like below:
http://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:8080/getalluser

While calling the API, I got Mixed content error and the request was blocked

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://masd.amea.xyz.com/' was loaded
over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
'http://microservice-svc.masd.svc.cluster.local:8080/users/getalluser'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

I tried using HTTPS to call the backend service but it didnt work either.
I tried exposing the backed to a DNS through load balancer and used the DNS endpoint to call the backend. it worked since it is a https request. But I feel this is not the right approach. calling the service directly will be the right approach.
Please let me know how to get over this issue. Any suggestion would be helpful.

The React application runs in the end user's browser, not inside the cluster, and it can't resolve the Kubernetes-internal .svc.cluster.local DNS names.  You need to expose your backend via an Ingress as well.  Ideally this uses the same host name as the frontend, so cross-origin restrictions won't apply.

Thans @DavidMaze.  Is there any way in React to call internal API's from the server and not from the browser ?  Currently I have exposed API through Ingress and utilizing it in my frontend like you suggested. But if there is a way to directly access the service through .svc.cluster.local endpoint it would be a better way and also will give a faster response

No, because the React application is running in the end user's browser.  Something running in a backend service could make a direct call inside the cluster, but that wouldn't be the React application itself.
